# Null Object Reference in Spinner.getselecteditem.tostring

Tags: android, android-spinner

I'm getting a null object reference when trying to get value of Spinner in my OnClick,this is how i'm setting the values of Spinner

```
DatabaseReference db1 = firebaseDatabase.getReference("USERS/"+getArguments().getString("Usr"));
db1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot.child("uList").getValue().toString() != null && tem)
        {
            String temp1 = dataSnapshot.child("uList").getValue().toString();
            String [] m =temp1.split(",");
            for(j=0;j<=m.length-1;j++){
                if(m[j] !=null && m[j] != "") {
                    UsrList.add(m[j]);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(!tem)
            {                              
                UsrList1.add("Not Applicable");
            }
            else
            {                               
                UsrList1.add("No Users have been added yet");
            }
        }
        usrAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, UsrList1);
        ul.setAdapter(usrAdapter1);
    }
}
```

The Spinner,arralist,arrayadapter have been defined in the Activity, but during my OnClick I'm not able to get the value of the spinner, it says null object reference.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String tString,yString;
    boolean temp;
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    switch(v.getId()) {          
        case R.id.btnN:                
            showToast(ul.getSelectedItem().toString());
```

I'm able to see the spinner data on the UI,its just while selecting i'm not getting the string.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please share logs...

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK NullPointerException:Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference at "showToast"

Comment: show what is `ul`, where it is declared and initialised..

Comment: also check `ul. getSelectedItemPosition()` before displaying selected object.

Comment: @ELITE It's declared in Activity before OnCreate,and initialised in Oncreate method

Comment: what `ul.getSelectedItemPosition();` this call returns...I think it is returning `-1`

Comment: @ELITE 
The problem was i was adding things to USrList and setting Usrlist1,a silly mistake

Answer (score 0):

> NullPointerException:Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference at "showToast"

from [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItem())

> The data corresponding to the currently selected item, or null if there is nothing selected.

When you click the button, there is nothing selected. So it return null in `getSelectedItem()`. Calling `toString()` on null with result in null pointer reference.

Comment: i have a valid selection made,the selection is "new",but it still throws me a null object which clearly is not the case

Answer (score 0):

if you want get value from spinner maybe you can try setOnItemSelectedListener not onClick.

```
ul.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                                   int position, long id) {

        String item = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub)

        }
    });
```

Comment: The problem was i was adding things to USrList and setting Usrlist1,a silly mistake